# php cron mails include links without hostname, base_url is missing

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, cron

We have a platform built on Codeigniter PHP, that occasionaly sents out mails through a CRON Job.
To not overload the system we place the entire mails as a BLOB in a database queue and than every x-minutes mails from that queue will be sent.

```
$mailTemplatePartials = load_template_passive_mail_volunteer($region->region_name);

//Create and sent a mail to volunteers (passive matching of vacancies)
$this->email->from(GENERAL_MAIL, 'Give a Day');
$this->email->to($vol->email);
$this->email->subject(lang("new_vacancies_matches"));
$message = $this->load->view($mailTemplatePartials, $mail_data, TRUE);
$this->email->message($message);
//Insert mail in the mail_queue_passive database table
insert_mail_in_passive_queue(GENERAL_MAIL, $vol->email, lang("new_vacancies_matches"), $this->email);
```

The 'load_template_passive_mail_volunteer' loads the actual mail view and in this view we built urls with the base_url() function. For instance:

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'design/img/interesses/grey/' . $interest->img; ?>" width="30" style="max-width: 1188px; border-radius: 0%;" class="mcnImage">
```

The 'insert_mail_in_passive_queue' will insert the entire mail into the database queue:

```
function insert_mail_in_passive_queue($from, $to, $subject, $mail_object) {
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('mail/mailQueuePassive_model');

    $mail = new stdClass();
    $mail->from = $from;
    $mail->to = $to;
    $mail->subject = $subject;
    $mail->mail_object = serialize($mail_object);

    return $CI->mailQueuePassive_model->add($mail);
}
```

So now in our database queue we have a complete mail object with correct layout and links, the entire mail content is already in place. So we do not create the content of the email in the CRON we only need to sent it still.

And then there is the CRON method that actually checks in the mailing queue if there are mails to be sent or not:

```
public function sendPassiveQueuingMails() {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //Make sure the script does not time out
    // this function can only be called from the command line
    if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
        echo "Access is only allowed from the command line";
        return;
    }

    $this->load->model('mail/mailQueuePassive_model');
    $mailsToSent = $this->mailQueuePassive_model->getAllNotSent();

    foreach ($mailsToSent as $mail) {
        $this->mailQueuePassive_model->setLock($mail->mail_id);
        $mailObject = unserialize($mail->mail_object);
        $mailSent = $mailObject->send();

        if ($mailSent == 1) {
            $this->mailQueuePassive_model->setSentSuccessfull($mail->mail_id);
            $this->mailQueuePassive_model->setUnlock($mail->mail_id);
        } else {
            //In een future uitbreiding kan hier de "amount of retries" ook telkens met 1 verhoogd worden, kan gebruikt worden door een slim algoritme (kolom moet nog aangemaakt worden dan)
            $this->mailQueuePassive_model->setUnlock($mail->mail_id);
        }
    }
}
```

If we test this system with one mail it works perfect. 
The mail arrives and contains correct images and urls back to our website.

But when we activate this with live data we see that the mails for some reason don't include the hostname in resource urls (images) and plain links anymore. This will be around 400 mails triggered systematically with a 2 minute (or something) delay by the CRON job.

So for instance an image or a link in a mail will not work anymore because the link consists of:
https://nl-be/design/img/interesses/grey/interesse-reizen-grey.svg
instead of:
https://www.mydomein.be/design/img/interesses/grey/interesse-reizen-grey.svg

[image]
[image]

Does anyone has ever experienced something like this or knows what can possibly go wrong?

These are not the first mails we sent through CRON jobs but these are the first mails where we get completly wrong urls.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question: What do you think the `base_url()` of a CRON job is... _HINT_ batch jobs have no url_

Comment: @RiggsFolly in the CRON there is no context so no base_url. However we load the entire mail already in the BLOB before the CRON runs. So all urls are already created and correct in the BLOB. Then when the emails are sent with the CRON the urls miss their hostname. I updated the Q above that we do not CREATE content of any sorts in the CRON.

Comment: @RiggsFolly like stated in the Question when we test this system with 1 or 2 mails everything is perfect. This shows we do not built anything inside the CRON otherwise this test should fail as well..